# Tag search down on SO

Tags: bug, tag-search

There's no results for tag searches at the moment:

[image]

This is for any tag I tried, e.g. [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost), [boost-phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-phoenix), etc.

Comment: No exact repo here. It's definitely slow for me on the tags you mention. I know the searching system has timeout. And if it goes over that timeout, you'll get a blank page/no results.

Comment: Ah it was intermittent. It seems to be back working now. Leaving it up as documentation. Popular myth has it that tag search only suffers on Saturdays. Increasingly I find this to be untrue

Comment: I had an intermittent 0 result page (happened once a few seconds ago) but I was not doing a tag-based search. I was just refreshing the `active` question tab on meta. Refresh, and poof: all the questions are gone. (Like in the screenshot above.) Refresh again, and poof: all the questions are back.

Comment: Surely related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275120/mso-questions-not-loading

Comment: I'd be inclined to vote it as a dupe of that one @Jongware

Comment: There is a third report: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275119/pending-socket-connection-happening-a-lot-lately, also surely related. (Dupe close? The others are unanswered (as yet).)

Comment: Heh - I searched before posting my dupe. In the time it took me to grab quick screenshots and type the question a few others have already mentioned it.