# MSO Questions Not Loading

Tags: bug, status-norepro, meta, front-page

I've been getting this intermittently over the last week or so. Here on MSO the questions don't always load in when visiting the front page, as you can see below;

[image: MSO Blank Front Page (Questions)]

If a question is updated in that time, the dialogue appears informing you of that, and when you click only that question is loaded in. See below;

[image: MSO One Question Loaded]

This seems to be a problem for around 5-10 minutes, with multiple reloads including requesting a new version of the page (Ctrl+F5) failing to solve the problem. The page also loads immediately, so it's not a timeout issue. Anyone else having this problem? Is it a known issue?

PS: **No photoshop was used on these screenshots**, except for the cropping of course.

PPS: Not had this problem since posting question, but has it been fixed or are others still experiencing issues?

Comment: Just got that as well, for the very first time. Very odd. Refreshing the page helped. (Nice PS. "No actual pixels were harmed ...")

Comment: https://twitter.com/shanemadden/status/525068825054560256

Comment: not only for meta... It would happen sometimes on main site also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. We experienced numerous attempted DDoS attacks last week. I'm almost certain that this was the cause of your issues. Questions will not appear in the case that the time taken to load them is too long, which would happen under heavy (DDoS-like) load. You should *not* be experiencing this issue at this time, since we are not *currently* being DDoS'd. Sorry for the inconvenience.